# notifyListeners in Flutter not working correctly

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Model that calls notifyListeners and a `ScopedModelDescendant` widget in a build, even though it 100% calls the notifyListeners(), it doesn't update the build.

I looked into it and it seems the Model doesnt have anything in the _listeners.

```
class MyModel extends Model {

  void notify() {
    notifyListeners();
  }

}

class Main extends StatefulWidget {

  _MainState createState() => _MainState();

}

class _MainState extends State<StatefulWidget> {

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScopedModel<MyModel>(
      model: MyModel(),
      child: ScopedModelDescendant<MyModel>(
        builder: (context, child, model) {...}
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So as expected when I call notify, whatever is in the {...} should get rebuild, but it doesnt.

Comment: did you call notify() in ScopedModelDescendant with model.notify() ?

Comment: check `ScopedModelDescendant` constructor parameters

Comment: @Daniyar I called it in a whole other build, this is just simplyfied code, but i didnt call it in the ScopedModelDescendant thats for sure

Comment: @pskink What do you mean, the constructor of ScopedModelDescendant in general or of my model ?

Comment: i mean constructor of [ScopedModelDescendant](https://pub.dev/documentation/scoped_model/latest/scoped_model/ScopedModelDescendant-class.html) widget class

Comment: @pskink Whats with it, how does that help ?

Comment: ah sorry, i didnt notice that `rebuildOnChange` parameter by default is set to `true` - are you sure you are on the newest version of `scoped_model`? maybe in the past it was set to `false`?

Comment: @pskink i lloked at the Constructor it sets it to true and to be 100% secure i set it to true manually

Comment: ok, tried to use `ScopedModel.of` instead of `ScopedModelDescendant`? i always used [of](https://pub.dev/documentation/scoped_model/latest/scoped_model/ScopedModel/of.html)  method and it works just fine - notice though it uses "reversed" `rebuildOnChange` - the default is `false`

Comment: So i just create a final model and then ? Edit: It worked, thank you

Comment: hmm, strange that `ScopedModelDescendant` did not work... (i always felt that `of` method is better somehow, and coherent with flutter's `Theme.of` / `Navigator.of` / `Scafflod.of` etc)

Comment: now i see it: `ScopedModelDescendant` is a direct child of `ScopedModel` - i dont think it will work - but it is just my wild guess

Comment: Ok So how do i do it cause actually ScopedModel.of also doesnt work

Comment: `Edit: It worked, thank you` - so it worked or not?

Comment: No, i thought it had but it doesnt

Comment: https://github.com/brianegan/scoped_model/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart

Comment: Still not working, anymore ideas ?

Comment: what is not working? it is an official `scoped_model` demo - did you run it as it is - without ANY modifications?

Comment: Sure it runs but if i use it just like in thw example it doesnt work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56837928/notifylisteners-in-flutter-not-working-correctly#comment100246289_56837928, tried to add some widgets between model and descendant (as it is in the demo i linked)? for example add `Main` as a child of model, so the tree looks like: model > main > descendant?

Comment: I actually added the ScopedModel in the beginning so theres a lot in between

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate this behavior using the [sample](https://pub.dev/packages/scoped_model/example) provided in `scoped_model`, but the screen updates as expected. I did some modifications on the sample to match part of your code. You can try this out.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:scoped_model/scoped_model.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp(
    model: CounterModel(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final CounterModel model;

  const MyApp({Key key, @required this.model}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // At the top level of our app, we'll, create a ScopedModel Widget. This
    // will provide the CounterModel to all children in the app that request it
    // using a ScopedModelDescendant.
    return ScopedModel<CounterModel>(
      model: model,
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Scoped Model Demo',
        home: CounterHome('Scoped Model Demo'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// Start by creating a class that has a counter and a method to increment it.
//
// Note: It must extend from Model.
class CounterModel extends Model {
  int _counter = 0;

  int get counter => _counter;

  void increment() {
    // First, increment the counter
    _counter++;

    // Then notify all the listeners.
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class CounterHome extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  CounterHome(this.title);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScopedModelDescendant<CounterModel>(
        builder: (context, child, model) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('You have pushed the button this many times:'),
              // Create a ScopedModelDescendant. This widget will get the
              // CounterModel from the nearest parent ScopedModel<CounterModel>.
              // It will hand that CounterModel to our builder method, and
              // rebuild any time the CounterModel changes (i.e. after we
              // `notifyListeners` in the Model).
              Text(
                model.counter.toString(),
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        // Use the ScopedModelDescendant again in order to use the increment
        // method from the CounterModel
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: model.increment,
          tooltip: 'Increment',
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Furthermore, I'm curious on why the need to use [`scope_model`](https://pub.dev/packages/scoped_model/) to update the widgets on the screen when [stateful and stateless widgets](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/interactive#creating-a-stateful-widget) can be easily updated.